# Динамическое изменение TableView в Swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Есть приложение, в котором снизу есть поле ввода, над полем расположена таблица. При вводе текста в swift 1.2 достаточно было изменить высоту родительской вьюхи на высоту клавиатуры. В swift 2 такое не работает. Я знаю, что в swift 2 нужно изменить отступ снизу. Проблема в том, что не срабатывает анимация прокрутки таблицы. Точнее срабатывает, но рывками. В swift 1.2 все было плавно. Как изменить высоту таблицы и при этом добиться плавной анимации прокрутки?

UPD: Экран. Разделен на 2 части. В нижней - вьюха с полем ввода и кнопкой. В верхней - вьюха с таблицей. При заполненной таблице, когда записей болше чем может отобразиться на экране, таблица прокручивается до последней строки снизу. Когда активирован ввод с клавиатуры, то нижний блок с полем ввода поднимается на высоту клавиатуры. Таблица должна сжаться и прокрутиться вниз. Но анимация прокрутки происходит рывками. В 1.2 такого не было.

```
func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {

    let duration = sender.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
    let curve = sender.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt

    let info: NSDictionary = sender.userInfo!
    let value: NSValue = info.valueForKey("UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey") as! NSValue
    let keyboardSize: CGSize = value.CGRectValue().size

    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {

        self.contentBottomConstrains.constant = keyboardSize.height
        self.bottomBox.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: self.messages.count-1, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: true)

        }, completion: nil)

}
```

contentBottomConstrains - это отступ от супервью нижнего блока снизу
у таблицы стоит вертикальный отступ от контейнера с полеем ввода.

Comment: Какой нибудь код покажете?

Comment: И желательно более подробно объяснить проблему, не понятно, что вообще Вы хотите сделать, и что у Вас не получается.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko, пожалуйста.

Comment: @ИльяТерезников вроде расписал подробнее

Comment: @МаксимВласов и случайно, нет такого эффекта, что как будто бы разные анимации проходят у нижней view и клавиатуры? Или проблема просто в том, что таблица не правильно сжимается?

Comment: @ИльяТерезников, не совсем. Сдвигается панель вроде вовермя, но сначала происходит как бы перекрытие таблицы, а потом срабатывает анимация. А с таблицой вообще беда: она вроде сворачивается, но анимация прокрутки происходит рывками.

Answer (score 1):

1. Вынесите метод скролинга таблицы в completion блок, дергание у вас происходит потому, что вы пытаетесь исполнять анимированный скрол в методе уже исполняемой анимации.
2. Если вы листаете таблицу в низ, используйте UITableViewScrollPositionBottom.
3. Попробуйте обойтись без constraint, вычисляйте `bottomView.y = self.view.height - keyboardHeight- bottomView.height;`

Comment: если вынести в комплит, то сначала происходит смещение и изменение размера и только потом скролинг.

Comment: @МаксимВласов само собой, многие мессенджеры по этому подходу работают, что изменяется размер, выдвигается клавиатура, а потом анимированный скроллинг вниз

Comment: Да как раз не все. Телеграм, например, сдвигает таблицу плавно. Последнее сообщение всегда на экране.